# Problem installing gems for the first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm playing with rails for the first time and running into errors with gems. If I enter the command, `sudo ./gem install rmagick`, I get the following:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rmagick-2.12.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rmagick-2.12.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for rmagick-2.12.2...
```

And then I get:

```
No definition for Image_edge

No definition for Image_emboss

No definition for Image_encipher

No definition for Image_enhance

No definition for Image_equalize

No definition for Image_equalize_channel

No definition for Image_erase_bang

No definition for Image_excerpt

No definition for Image_excerpt_bang

No definition for Image_export_pixels
```

etc, etc, for about 3 pages. I've installed ruby in /home/me/Languages/ruby which I guess is not standard, could that be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to worry about that. That's just RDOC saying that it doesn't have documentation for those functions. Although if it's any conciliation, I have 130 gems installed and have never seen this many rdoc errors.

Other than that, go ahead and use Rmagik it should work fine. :-)

Hope this helps!